# How to seal (caulk) replacement windows that have wrapping

Tags: windows, sealing, caulking

When installing replacement windows where do you put caulk, and does this change if you have aluminum wrap being put on the outside?  Does caulk go all the way around the window (between exterior moulding and window as well as at top and bottom), or just along the sides?  Do you also put caulk around the interior of the window between the window and the stops?

Comment: You're going to have to show us the situation. There's no one right location. It depends on many things.

Comment: Caulk it so that water cannot get in but also don't block the escape route for any water that does get in. Aside from that there are plenty of tutorials and videos online to watch.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to seal the window flange to the sheathing, over the rain-guard, using a generous amount of silicone caulking

Then treat the aluminum wrap like an extensive drip wrap, not a seal, that guides streaming water away from the window seams.

Wooden window casing can benefit from this, but vinyl casing needs no aluminum wrap, just a drip edge. Note that building codes require the drip edge on all horizontal seams, unless the window is protected by sufficiently deep roofing.

All layers of wrap & cladding should be lapped so that water streaming from above cannot stream in behind the cladding and trim. The amount of overlap is determined by the storminess of your climate.

It's usually ok for a bit of water to get behind trim and cladding (but not behind the rain shield), as long as it is not trapped there. The trim should have enough gapping so that any water still making it behind the trim can drip out from the bottom, and so that all seams can air-dry between rainfall. I apply exterior paint to all sides of trim wood.

What causes trouble on the exterior is water trapped between sill & trim where it can rot the trim because the trim never dries. This is a problem with seams that are tight and hold back water from behind.

What causes troubled on the inside is even the smallest amount of water that wicks in past the flange. This is where you need a caulked seal and where you can rely on caulking: it is protected from sun and temperature extremes because it is closest to the sheathing and most protected by trim, cladding and flange.

I do not rely on silicone or sealants or flashing tape alone, because they ultimately have limited life expectancy when cycled through cold and especially hot temperatures, and UV (if applicable).